# Z3 C API manage Z3_VAR_AST

Tags: z3

I try to write a custom print for a Z3_ast of Z3 in C, but I do not know how to manage the Z3_ast_kind of Z3_VAR_AST and Z3_FUNC_DECL_AST, I only know how to print the Z3_sort of Z3_VAR_AST (Z3_get_sort), about this variable value I have no ideas ???. And about the Z3_FUNC_DECL_AST, I couldn't find any accessors can get the function name, number of parameters and the parameters. Could you guys please help me? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at the file 'python/z3printer.py' in the Z3 distribution. It defines a custom pretty printer in Python. The Z3 python API is just a layer on top of the C API. So, it should be straightforward to convert this printer in C.

Regarding `Z3_VAR_AST`, the function

`unsigned Z3_API Z3_get_index_value(__in Z3_context c, __in Z3_ast a);`

returns the de-Brujin index for the variable. The meaning of the index is explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index
The variable names are stored in the quantifier AST. Note that, the names are irrelevant for Z3. They are stored just to make the output nice. The code in `z3printer.py` will keeps a stack with the variable names.

Regarding `Z3_FUNC_DECL_AST`, it is easier to handle than `Z3_VAR_AST`. ASTs of this kind are actually `Z3_func_decl`. Then the following APIs can be used to extract the information you want:

```
Z3_symbol Z3_API Z3_get_decl_name(__in Z3_context c, __in Z3_func_decl d);

Z3_decl_kind Z3_API Z3_get_decl_kind(__in Z3_context c, __in Z3_func_decl d);

unsigned Z3_API Z3_get_domain_size(__in Z3_context c, __in Z3_func_decl d);

unsigned Z3_API Z3_get_arity(__in Z3_context c, __in Z3_func_decl d);

Z3_sort Z3_API Z3_get_domain(__in Z3_context c, __in Z3_func_decl d, __in unsigned i);
```

Again, the file `z3printer.py` uses all these functions.