# Z3 API: Is inspection of AST possible

Tags: api, z3, abstract-syntax-tree

There is no direct way in Z3 to traverse an already existing `Z3_ast` for an expression, that much seems clear to me from the API. Is there however an indirect way how to, e.g., split a conjunction, substitute a term for a term in a `Z3_ast` obtained for example by `Z3_parse_smtlib2_string` or as an interpolant obtained with `Z3_get_interpolant` (these are output from Z3, so it makes sense to be able to examine them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traversal is possible, in the C API the functions for that are [Z3_get_app_num_args](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#gae8ad520b79b46c323863bacffa0e12c0) and [Z3_get_app_arg](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga49a576b11f9f6ca4a94670e538a84c6b). However, this works only if the AST is a function application (an app, cast via [Z3_to_app](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#gaf9345fd0822d7e9928dd4ab14a09765b) if necessary), other AST types may not have arguments to traverse (e.g., vars and numerals, see [Z3_ast_kind](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga015148ad21a032e79a496629651dedb8)).

Comment: The examples contain visitor patterns. For example under examples/c++ you will find the function called "visit".
void visit(expr const & e) {
    if (e.is_app()) {
        unsigned num = e.num_args();
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            visit(e.arg(i));
        }
        // do something
        // Example: print the visited expression
        func_decl f = e.decl();
        std::cout << "application of " << f.name() << ": " << e << "\n";
    }
    else if (e.is_quantifier()) {
        visit(e.body());  ...etc.

Comment: Thanks, so is every AST that gets constructed from other ASTs always a function application (e.g. `eq`, `lt`, `+`, `and`)? I guess that would make sense. Then I guess that variables and such can be examined via `get_symbol` (to get the name), and `get_sort` (to get the sort), right?

@NikolajBjorner: I completely missed there were examples. Thank you

Comment: No, but those that you mentioned are all function applications. Others include numerals, sort declarations, function declarations, bound (quantified) variables, and quantified expressions (they have a body, but no args), see Z3_ast_kind.

Comment: I am for example puzzled how to get a symbol for a `VAR_AST`.

Comment: VAR_ASTs are de-brujin indexed, bound variables, so primarily they have an index. To get a variable's name you need the corresponding QUANTIFIER_AST, which keeps a list of names that can be accessed via [Z3_get_quantifier_bound_name](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#gab554587e623297f7d953b030d71d08a6).

Comment: See also [Understanding the indexing of bound variables in Z3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816626/understanding-the-indexing-of-bound-variables-in-z3), [Understanding the indexing of bound variables in Z3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249646/z3-c-api-manage-z3-var-ast).