# Traversing z3 ast in java

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, z3

While I can see that there exists traversal for Z3 AST in C++ (outlined in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475007/z3-api-is-inspection-of-ast-possible)), I can't find its equivalent method in Java api, is there a way by which I can traverse the Z3 AST in Java?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the relevant functions are found here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/java/Expr.java

(I'm not a Java programmer, nor I have used these myself; so take this with a grain of salt!)

Comment: I am not sure which part of it did you mean, I do not see visitor pattern supported there, nor do I see how is it possible access elements/objects for each expression, for example, I would expect to be able to visit lhs and rhs of a binary expression, but as far as I can see this isn't there.

Comment: Good point. I think this is a better question to ask at their issues site: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues

Comment: The `visit` function from the C++ example gives the strategy, the Java function names are different only in capitalization and the `get` prefix. In general there is no RHS or LHS; `expr`s have arbitrary numbers of arguments that can be inspected via `Expr.getNumArgs` and `Expr.getArgs()[index]`.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger, it isn't exactly the visitor pattern that you'd expect, but yes I guess that should do the job. Thank you very much!